# Change the avatar ratio in bbPress login widget

Tags: bbpress, avatar

I am using bbPress on my site and have (bbPress) Login Widget on my sidebar.
Is there a way to change the default image size from 40 to 80 or other number?
here is the code from the core files:

`<?php echo get_avatar( bbp_get_current_user_id(), '40' ); ?>`

How do I change that default 40 px without editing the core files?
Can i filter it somehow?

Thanks in advance, you are my last hope to find answer to this problem of mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `'get_avatar'`:

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'wpse_67657_new_avatar', 10, 5 );

function wpse_67657_new_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt )
{
    // create a new img element or …
    $new = str_replace( 's=40', 's=80', $avatar );
    $new = str_replace( 'avatar-40', 'avatar-80', $new );
    $new = str_replace( " height='40' width='40'", " height='80' width='80'", $new );
    return $new;
}
```

Filtering the size only is currently not possible.

Comment: well if i want to change the size to 80 how should this function look like?

Comment: @Radi I have included an example now. It is not tested, more a general idea.